# .Net 2.0 - ControlPaint.DrawButton uses wrong color

Tags: c#, .net

When I call ControlPaint.DrawButton, the button that is drawn is in the non-themed background color.  How do I draw a control that looks like a button (including themed drawing) in .Net 2.0 (C#)?

Comment: What parameters are you passing in?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ControlPaint methods do not support visual styles, that's why it looks all messed up (try taking out this line of code in your Program.cs Application.EnableVisualStyles(); and everything will look like that button and you'll see what I mean.)

The correct method you should be using is the [ButtonRender.DrawButton(..)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.buttonrenderer.drawbutton.aspx) method. This does honor visual styles and will thus render correctly. Quick sample:

```
            ButtonRenderer.DrawButton(this.CreateGraphics(), 
            new Rectangle(20, 20, 100, 40),"Click me!",
            new Font(this.Font, FontStyle.Regular),false,
            System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.PushButtonState.Normal);
```

Comment: I looked for that for hours...  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The [first](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xebt4a7d.aspx) and [second overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/464fk752.aspx) have [`ButtonState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.buttonstate.aspx) as the last param.

I imagine you want: `ButtonState.Normal`, and what you're getting is `ButtonState.Flat` ?

Comment: I'm using normal and the borders look good, but not the background.  There doesn't seem to be a button version of ComboBoxRenderer.  Bummer.